# Is this valid ruby syntax?

Tags: ruby

```
hash = {:symbol, 'mental'}
```

Because I'm finding the above dotted around a project I'm working on, and I can't figure out whether this is due to an older version of Ruby or not.

Comment: What does the irb tell you?

Comment: It isn't valid in 1.9.3, I know that. But I'm fairly new to Ruby (year). However, I've never seen this syntax before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Valid in `Ruby 1.8` when you have right key value pair in order. And you need to have even number of elements in hash creation:

`hash = {:symbol, 'mental'}` same as  `hash = {:symbol => 'mental'}`

Some examples:

```
hash = {:symbol, 'mental', :name,'abc'}
 => {:symbol=>"mental", :name=>"abc"}

hash = {:symbol, 'mental', :name,'abc', :b}
=>  Syntax Error
```

Comment: This syntax is extremely unusual to see, and as it's not compatible with 1.9, it's being stamped out wherever it exists.

Comment: @tadman Yes, this is not compatible with 1.9. And so many things changed about Hash in 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a typo. I think that line should read:

```
hash = {:symbol => 'mental'}
```

This does seem to be valid for 1.8.7 ruby though...

Comment: Hmm..I think that's why. Project was originally 1.8.